# How to make the button disappear onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my code

```js
 function show() {
          var today = new Date();
          var h = today.getHours();
          var m = today.getMinutes();
          if (h < 10) h = "0" + h;
          if (m < 10) m = "0" + m;
          document.getElementById("pressbtn1").innerHTML  = h+":"+m;
        }
```

```html
<html>
      <button id="pressbtn1" onClick="show()">Press</button>
  
 </html>
```

how to make to button disappear onclick, I want to show the time only, not the time on the button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use another hidden tag for that purpose, for example:

```
<span id="timeHolder" style="display: none"><span>
<button id="pressbtn1" onClick="show()">Press</button>
```

and then:

```
var timeHolder = document.getElementById("timeHolder");
timeHolder.innerHTML  = h+":"+m;
timeHolder.style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById("pressbtn1").style.display = 'none';
```

This will be quite clear approach.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
`timeHolder.style.style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById("pressbtn1").style.display = 'none';`
is useful

Answer (score 3):

You can use basic CSS to remove the default button styles.

```js
var button = document.getElementById("pressbtn1");

function show() {
  var today = new Date();
  var h = today.getHours();
  var m = today.getMinutes();
  if (h < 10) h = "0" + h;
  if (m < 10) m = "0" + m;
  button.innerHTML = h + ":" + m;
  button.classList.add('hasTime');
}
```

```css
.hasTime {
  background: #fff;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="pressbtn1" onClick="show()">Press</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Set visibility to hidden using `element.style.visibility=hidden` and put the time in a paragraph

```js
function show() {
  var today = new Date();
  var h = today.getHours();
  var m = today.getMinutes();
  if (h < 10) h = "0" + h;
  if (m < 10) m = "0" + m;
  document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = h + ":" + m;
  document.getElementById("pressbtn1").style.visibility = "hidden"
}
```

```html
<html>
<button id="pressbtn1" onClick="show()">Press</button>
<p id="a"></p>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use remove() method.

```js
function show() {
  var today = new Date();
  var h = today.getHours();
  var m = today.getMinutes();
  if (h < 10) h = "0" + h;
  if (m < 10) m = "0" + m;
  document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = h + ":" + m;
  document.getElementById("pressbtn1").remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<button id="pressbtn1" onClick="show()">Press</button>
<p id="a"></p>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button id="pressbtn1" onClick="show()">Press</button>
<script>
function show() {
                var today = new Date();
                var h = today.getHours();
                var m = today.getMinutes();
                if (h < 10) h = "0" + h;
                if (m < 10) m = "0" + m;
                document.getElementById("pressbtn1").parentElement.innerHTML  = h+":"+m;
              }
</script>
```

The code above will show time on the parent of the button which is the body tag in this case, it means instead of having a button tag inside the body tag you'll have time and date text inside the body tag